# addAll() method in Set implementation does not work

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I am trying to implement my own Set with an `ArrayList` in Java. I have written the method `add()` which is responsible for adding a new element in the Set, the method `contains`, which returns true if an element is found in the Set and the method `addAll` , which I want to add all the elements which the collection in the parameter contains in the Set. Despite that, when I create two objects of the class Set and invoke the method on the i get an error message on Eclipse saying : `The method addAll(Collection) in the type Set is not applicable for the arguments Set` .This is the code I have written for the implementation so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class Set<E>{
private ArrayList<E> List = new ArrayList<>();

public boolean add(E e) {
    if(contains(e))
        return false;
    return List.add(e);
}

public boolean addAll(Collection<E> e) {
    for(E i : e)
    {
        if(!List.contains(i)) {
            List.add(i);
        }   
    }
    return true;
}
 public boolean contains(E e) {
    return List.contains(e);
}
```

This is the class from which I instantiate the objects and the method invoking I do on them:

```
public class NewClass
{   
   private Set setOne;
   private Set setTwo;

 public static void main(String[] args) { 
    setOne.addAll(setTwo);
}
```

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Very simply, your "Set" isn't a Set.  It's your own, completely unrelated class that you happened to name "S-e-t"" :(  You can use explicit namespaces to disambuguate your "Set" from "java.util.collection.Set".  Or, better, 'java.util.Set`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Set` does not implement the [`java.util.Collection` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). Thus, your `Set` is not a `Collection`.

The `Collection` interface requires quite some methods to be implemented, but if you let your `Set<E> implements Collection<E>` and implement all required methods, your code will work.

As a quick&dirty fix, you could add a method `public boolean addAll(Set<? extends E> set)` to your `Set`.

Some remarks on your code:

- Following the [PECS mnemonic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super), you may want to change the signature of your existing `addAll(...)` method to:

  ```
  public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> e)
  ```
- In Java, varialbe-, attribute- and method-names should start with a lowercase letter (`private ArrayList<E> List = new ArrayList<>();` -> `private ArrayList<E> list = new ArrayList<>();`).
- You should give your variables and parameters meaningful names (e.g. `collection` instead of `e` or `entry` instead of `i`).
- It is regarded as bad practice to neglect optional parentheses around `if`-, `else`-, `for`-, ... bodies.